# Java Excercis 16 RandomWalk

Tags: java

I am running a program that starts someone in the middle of a 7 foot bridge and you have to generate 1s and 0s to simulate forward and backward steps. It is supposed to calculate how many steps it took the person to fall off either forwards or backwards, and i am not done but when i run it, it never stops generating numbers. this is what i have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class RandomWalk {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int forwardstep=4;
        int backwardstep=4;
        int average;
        int randomnum=0;
        int attemptnum=0;
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(forwardstep<7||backwardstep<7){
            randomnum=(int)(2*Math.random()+0);// random number generator//
            System.out.println(randomnum);
            attemptnum+=1;
            if(randomnum==1){
                forwardstep+=1;
                backwardstep-=1;
            }
            else if(randomnum==0){
                backwardstep+=1;

                forwardstep-=1;
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (forwardstep<7 || backwardstep<7)
```

You are looking for a fall off one side of the bridge so one of these will always be true. You want to check rather if one of these if false therefore;

```
while (forwardstep<7 && backwardstep<7)
```

Comment: After running through a debugger, I was able to find the same problem. You got your answer first :P

Answer (score 0):

Because when you add one to one of your variables you always quit one on the other. For example, look at this:

forwardstep=4;
backwardstep=4;

```
5-3,6-3,7-3
```

But when the other variable enter in the if, then you will have this:

```
6-4,5-4,4-6,3-7
```

So, it's impossible that in the same time both variables will be equals to 7. Maybe you have to change the condition of your while to && (AND operator).